# Как работает поиск в shodan.io?

Tags: python, сеть

Всем привет!
кто-нибудь знает как работает shodan?
вот знаю, что он ищет по банерам, вроде бы. но не особо понимаю как их ставить...
вот есть  у меня web-сервер на flask с белым ip-адресом, как мне сделать так, чтобы shodan мог обнаружить мой web-server?

Comment: а он разве не уязвимости анализирует?

Comment: да он все анализирует, все ищет.
вот я хочу чтобы он смог найти меня по банеру, но я не знаю как это сделать

Comment: мне кажется есть какие то критерии для него, попробуйте посмотреть в пользовательском соглашении

Comment: в faq сайта же [написано](https://help.shodan.io/the-basics/credit-types-explained): оплатите им сканирование указанного ip-адреса — они и просканируют.